# Как добавить массив строк в словарь plist на iOS?

Tags: xcode, строки, ios, массивы

Есть таблица со списком слов и чекмарками. Если слово выбрано - оно добавляется в массив, который потом пишется в словарь plist. У меня добавляется и удаляется только одна строка. Если выбираю другую строку - она перезаписывает прежнюю. Гуглил полдня, не понял что нужно сделать, пробовал через копирование массива - не получилось. Вот мой код:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    bool isSelected = (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark);

    NSString *path = [DOCUMENTS stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"userData.plist"];

    NSMutableDictionary *data = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path];

    NSMutableArray *newData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    if (isSelected) {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    } else {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        [newData addObject:cell.textLabel.text];
    }

    [data setObject:newData forKey:@"PersonalQualities"];

    NSData *dataToPlist = [NSPropertyListSerialization dataWithPropertyList:data format:NSPropertyListXMLFormat_v1_0 options:0 error:nil];

    [dataToPlist writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {    
[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

bool isSelected = (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark);

NSString *path = [DOCUMENTS stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"userData.plist"];

NSMutableDictionary *dataDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path];

cell.accessoryType=isSelected? UITableViewCellAccessoryNone:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;

NSArray *oldData=dataDictionary[@"PersonalQualities"];
NSMutableArray *newData=[NSMutableArray new];

if (oldData!=nil)
    [newData addObjectsFromArray:oldData];

[newData addObject:cell.textLabel.text];

[dataDictionary setObject:newData forKey:@"PersonalQualities"];

NSData *dataToPlist = [NSPropertyListSerialization dataWithPropertyList:dataDictionary format:NSPropertyListXMLFormat_v1_0 options:0 error:nil];

[dataToPlist writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
```

}

Comment: Работает, но пока наполовину. Новые строки добавляются в массив, а не перезаписываются в одну строку как раньше. Когда ставишь галочку в списке - строка добавляется в массив, ставишь галочку на следующей строке - следующая строка добавляется в массив, ОК. Но когда убираешь галочку, эта строка не удаляется из массива, а дублируется.

Comment: Получилось!

`NSMutableArray *newData=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:data[@"PersonalQualities"]];

    if (isSelected) {
        [newData removeObject:cell.textLabel.text];
    } else {
        [newData addObject:cell.textLabel.text];
    }`